# How to access a backend web application in datapower using OAuth?

Tags: web-applications, ibm-datapower

Can anyone please help how to configure a service that access an external backend web application in datapower. I searched many sites but still not able to achieve. Please provide any simple service that access a backend external web application configuration pdf or links available.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/ibm-datapower/datapower-tutorials/blob/master/getting-started/hello-world-gateway.md

You can explore it as a way to get started and see how things works. There are a few other tutorials in the same folder.

Typically, what you want is:

- created a Multi-Protocol Gateway
- add an HTTP/HTTPS Front Protocol Handler that listens on the port where you want to receive requests on
- configure the backend URL where you will send requests to
- create a multi-protocol gateway processing policy

Comment: Hi Francisco, I have tried the link but the processing policy is going down. I tried to delete some methods which I imported but it's same.